Attach functions to QGIS processing algorithms
I am trying to find a way to attach a function to run whenever any processing algorithm either starts, succeeds or fails in the main QGIS application.
The functions should be attached when a plugin is loaded, so my main issue is finding the objects that send these signals in PyQgis.
The closest I've found so far is the QgsProcessingRecentAlgorithmLog, but it only has one signal (changed) and it only sends that when the name of the last used algorithm changes (so if you run buffer 10 times in a row you only get 1 signal).
Is there some sort of processing manager for the main application?

I found the answer to my question, and also a workaround once the "high road" answer kept crashing QGIS.
The correct way (crashes QGIS)
The "high road" way is to use the signals from the QgsHistoryProviderRegistry class.
Theoretically it could have multiple history providers, but for most users it will only have the processing plugin as a "QgsAbstractHistoryProvider" meaning that when the QgsHistoryProviderRegistry gets the entryAdded or entryUpdated signals, it would likely be from a processing algorithm.
I already opened an issue regarding those signals crashing QGIS,
so when the issue is fixed something like this should work:
history = QgsGui.historyProviderRegistry()

def onEntryAdded(*args):
    print("entry added!!!")


history.entryAdded.connect(onEntryAdded)

The workaround
I found that bypassing the crashes was easiest by querying QgsHistoryProviderRegistry with its queryEntries method.
This can be done between two date-time stamps and when you want to replace signals, you can just use a timer to query the results every second.
So this works for me:
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QTimer, QDateTime

history = QgsGui.historyProviderRegistry()

def check_processing_entry(self):
   entries = history.queryEntries(QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(-1),QDateTime.currentDateTime())
   if len(entries) == 0:
     return
   else:
      print("entry added!!!")


timer = QTimer()
timeout.connect(check_processing_entry)
timer.start(1000)

This is a simplified version of what i used, you can see the full code in repository of the QGIS sound effects plugin - in the function here, notice that I check what was the ID of the last entry and save it to avoid false positives.
